# How is data from Arrays and sutch, in contracts actually stored in the blockchain?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, dapps

How is data from instance variables in contracts actually stored in the blockchain? Say I have a simple contract like the example Token contract:

```
contract MyToken {
    /* This creates an array with all balances */
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    /* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
    function MyToken(
        uint256 initialSupply
        ) {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;              // Give the creator all initial tokens
    }

    /* Send coins */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
        if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw;           // Check if the sender has enough
        if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw; // Check for overflows
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                     // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to the recipient
    }
}
```

Where is the data in balanceOf stored? How might I be able to get this information without adding a function to the Contract just to return say the balance for an address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1-the data is stored in the contract's [storage](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Development-Tutorial#basics-of-the-ethereum-blockchain) (which is located in the blockchain) every contract has its own storage think of it as an associated disk.

2-you can get the data using whether public e.g

```
 mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
```

so every time you could get the result without the need of calling a function (solidity set a getter for you).

[image]

or you could set a getter (without declaring your variable public) to return the balance of any address you provide :

```
    function balance_get(address add) returns (uint256)
{
return balanceOf[ add];
}
```

Comment: Do getters in this case cost any gas?

Comment: yes they do, you will pay gas

Comment: If you add the keyword `constant` before the `returns` keyword, you will not have to pay any gas. See the source code at https://etherscan.io/address/0xa74476443119a942de498590fe1f2454d7d4ac0d#code for an example.